# Installing specific R package from specific branch from github repo on travis-ci

Tags: r, github, package, branch, travis-ci

I am developing a package which depends on a different package of mine which is still on github. I am using travis-ci to test the package. I added the following to the .travis.yml file to install the dmdScheme package from the dev branch:

```
language: r
r_github_packages: r-lib/remotes#340
r_github_packages: rkrug/dmdScheme#dev
```

but I get the following error at [travis](https://travis-ci.com/Exp-Micro-Ecol-Hub/emeScheme/jobs/205926600)

```
Installing R packages from GitHub: rkrug/dmdScheme#dev
0.19s$ Rscript -e 'remotes::install_github(c("rkrug/dmdScheme#dev"))'
Error in parse_repo_spec(repo) : 
  Invalid git repo specification: 'rkrug/dmdScheme#dev'
Calls: <Anonymous> -> lapply -> FUN -> parse_git_repo -> parse_repo_spec
Execution halted
The command "Rscript -e 'remotes::install_github(c("rkrug/dmdScheme#dev"))'" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

The remotes package is installed.

My question:

What is the correct syntax, to specify the branch (or `ref` in general) to be used in the command `r_github_packages`?

Comment: Have you tried with an `@` instead of a `#`?

Comment: My other suggestion also would be to specify this in your `DESCRIPTION` rather than `.travis.yml`

Comment: Thanks for the `@` - will be trying it out in a minute. Concerning `DESCRIPTION`: I already have a drat repo, and I will add that one to the `DESCRIPTION` when releasing in the `master` branch - well, I could actually do that for the `dev` branch as well. You mean `Remotes: rkrug/dmdScheme@dev` - correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. I have no idea whether it would work, I just know that's the other way to specify GitHub dependencies.

Comment: The `@` works perfectly. Thanks. I would like to keep it in the `.travis.yml` though, to let the user decied which version to install (I will test against `master` and `dev` of `dmdScheme` in a matrix - let's see if it works.

Comment: Oh - and if you make the `@` an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As we can see at the [Devtools dependencies vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/vignettes/dependencies.html), we can use `@` to specify specific commits, etc. So, you need:

```
r_github_packages: rkrug/dmdScheme@dev
```